# Have any helicopter or gyro copter rotors driven by tip propellers been built

Tags: rotorcraft, tip-jets

I remember the 4 bladed X wing and a two bladed tip jet rotors that were driven by compressed air, in the 1990s.  I believe there was a early 1900 rotor that was driven by propellers at the tips.  And, I think was there a human powered gyro copter that had propellers at the tip.  Does anyone have any references to tip propeller driven rotors?

My real question is what are the flight conditions where tip propeller driven is beneficial.  At first glance, the power required to drive the propellers is in addition to the power required to drive the rotor, so there wouldn't be any flight conditions where the tip propeller drive is better than shaft drive or tip jet drive or tip compressed air drive.  It's possible that for light thrust or small induced main rotor power, that a tip propeller could require less power.

Comment: What do you mean by a 'tip jet propeller'? Surely it's one or the other?

Comment: The concept is a two bladed rotor driven by two two-bladed propellers at the tips of the rotor.  So the rotor has low twist, similar to a helicopter rotor.  And the small propellers have twist like an airplane propeller.

Comment: Look at this concept.  https://hackaday.com/2022/08/08/large-tip-driven-copter-turns-very-slowly/

Comment: You should edit your question to clarify what you're after. You're currently referring to _"tip jet propellers"_. You're getting tip jets because they existed. If you want tip propellers you should make that clear.

Comment: You right, let me change the wording to emphasize tip propeller drive.

Comment: You're correct that the phrase tip jet propeller was incorrect.  I meant tip propeller.

Answer (score 1):

You are describing a propeller-driven propeller. This idea pops up from time to time, but always encounters the same fundamental problems, as follows.

First of all, the gyroscopic stresses on the propeller at the tip of the blade where the blade is rotating at ~800 RPM and the propeller is going ~2500 RPM are enormous, and would require an enormously strong main hub assembly.

Second, a main rotor going ~800 RPM has its tips approaching the speed of sound, as are the tips of an ordinary prop going ~2500 RPM. The combined air velocity at the tips of the propeller will be supersonic even when the helicopter is stationary. Any forward velocity then gets vector-added to the other velocity components and the problem gets worse. Cyclic stresses on the roots of the propeller blades will have a very strong once-per-revolution component which will not be good.

Finally, the windmilling drag of a dead tip propeller would probably make autorotation of the main rotor impossible.

Comment: I'm looking for tip propeller driven rotor design.

Comment: OK, got it.  -NN

Comment: The original question was misleading.  I've modified it to emphasize tip propeller driven.

Comment: I'd add also the similar problem of the jet version, that is, making the power (electrical or mechanical) reliably reach the tips of the main rotor.

Answer (score 0):

Fairey Aviation built the [Jet Gyrodyne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fairey_Jet_Gyrodyne)(first  flight 1954), as a precursor to the [Rotodyne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fairey_Rotodyn)(first flight 1957). The Rotodyne was intended for civil and military applications, but attracted no orders, in part due to the noise from the tip jets.

The Jet Gyrodyne was originally intended to be scrapped, but survived and can be seen today at [The Museum of Berkshire Avaiation](https://www.museumofberkshireaviation.co.uk/)

Some parts of the Rotodyne survive (but not a complete airframe) and can be seen at [The Helicopter Museum](http://www.helicoptermuseum.co.uk/)

**Jet Gyrodyne:**

[image]

<sup>[Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Fairey_Jet_Gyrodyne-1.jpg)</sup>

**Fairey Rotodyne**

[image]

<sup>[Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:SFF_002-1055526_Fairey_Rotodyne.jpg)</sup>

Comment: The Rotodyne was said (by a UK test pilot) to 'stop conversations from a mile away'.

Comment: I'm not looking for tip jet rotor, looking for tip propeller rotor.  Different specific thrust range.